# Attaching cookies to JMS requests via HTTP-Transport

Tags: java, cookies, jms, jboss7.x

Up front I am not a java developer but a middleware admin. I am trying to solve a problem we are encountering in our java application. The application consists of a server side application and a java client side application.

The environment consists of multiple JBoss 7 instances running in standalone mode behind a load balancer.

For most of the clients communication back to the server side the LB inserts a cookie to maintain persistence to the initial serverside node the client connects to due to our code inserting the cookie into all future requests. This works for all REST calls as we expect it to.

However the client also makes JMS connections back to the server side via an HTTP-Transport configured in standalone.xml

These connections are being seen by the loadbalancer as new connections and distributed in a round robin fashion since there is no cookie present in the request.

For the portion of code that handles the REST calls we are using httpclient.jar from Apache to manage the connection and insert the cookies.  The JMS over HTTP-Transport connections are only using the standard java libs from the following import:

```
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.ExceptionListener;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
```

It seems to me that in order to insert the cookie into the JMS over HTTP request we need to use Httpclient.jar to manage the connection as we do with REST calls or some other 3rd party library.  However I have been unsuccessful in explaining this to the developers.  Am I on the right track in my thinking or is this simply not possible with JMS over HTTP-Transport.  Can you suggest a 3rd party library or give a more "developer" explanation of what i am suggesting.

Thanks

Comment: Does the JMS connection actually use HTTP throughout or does it simply use HTTP for the initial connection and then an HTTP upgrade causes the connection to change to a bare TCP connection?  As I understand it, JBoss uses the latter mechanism as a way to support multiple services on a single port (i.e. the HTTP port).

Comment: I do not fully understand the HTTP upgrade concept however from what I can tell the JMS connection continues to be routed over port 80 through and f5 load balancer which then routes based on round robin since no cookie is being maintained. Does the HTTP Upgrade cause future traffic to not have any HTTP headers? This traffic is request -> response; request->response so I would assume that each request would be treated as a new HTTP request complete with headers and any cookie information that we could attach.

Comment: Can you add the messaging subsystem configuration to the question as well as details about what connection factory the clients are looking up?